# Measure resistance of multiple unknown resistors with single analog pin

Tags: transistors, resistance, voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

I'm currently using the circuit below the measure the resistance of multiple resistors (R1 and R2) using a voltage divider with a known resistance (R1). I'm using a PNP transistor for every unknown resistor to be able to measure them separately.

The goal is to be able to measure a lot of different unknown resistors with a single analog pin. Is there a better way to do this?

[image]

Comment: What precision and accuracy are you after?

Comment: I smell an XY problem here, why do you even want to do that?

Comment: It seems trivial to determine an unknown R with a load and linear incremental drop or use a DMM.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use switched current sources instead of using BJT's to switch voltage. With the current source, you can also change the range so you can also measure smaller resistors more precisely than with this setup. With a current source, you wouldn't need a second resistor to build a voltage divider, but can instead directly measure the resistor. If you use a single current source an an analog multiplexer, you can use a known resistor for calibration of the setup and your voltage reference. The current source will also eliminate some of the inaccuracy that you get as the 5V supply voltage is anything but well defined.

What you haven't said at all is what kind of precision you want to achieve. If all you need is 10% then a very simple setup is enough. If you need better than 0.1% then you need better analog circuitry.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use analog multiplexer 74HC4051 or alike, they are cheap and reliable. It's internal resistance is 50-100Ohm, so it's good idea to short one channel to ground, measure the switch resistance, and then subtract from the actual measurement.